# Android folding animation in facebook like slider

Tags: android, slider

I am working on a small module in which I have to use **Folding animation** with **facebook like slider** I have done with **facebook like slider**.Could any one suggest me how could I implement folding animation when slider is going to open or close.

Please have a look of image:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project in [GitHub](https://github.com/tibi1712/FoldingNavigationDrawer-Android) for **Folding Animation**

https://github.com/tibi1712/FoldingNavigationDrawer-Android

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying I have explored the FoldingLayout library but I need to put the folding animation at outer content not in inner content.This is actually troubling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to master the folding animation, you may read, run and examine [this](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/shareables/devbytes/FoldingLayout.zip) great source-code by DevBytes.

Furthermore. you can watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vabSSFCSkSg) video in which the writer of the above code explains his code line by line.